# Sending data to header of _Layout.cshtml regardless of what page the user is on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a notifications badge in the header of my _Layout.cshtml file. This is so I can constantly show the user their notifications regardless of what page they are on.

```
<a href="#">Notifications <span class="badge">@ViewData["NotificationCount"]</span></a><br>
```

However, I am wondering if there are better ways to do this. It seems like I need to do the following at the top of every single one of my views:

```
@{
    ViewData["ReminderCount"] = Model.Notifications.Count();
}
```

This also means I need to have a list of notifications as part of every single page ViewModel throughout my application.

Am I missing something here? I feel like there has to be a better way to handle things like this in ASP.NET MVC.

The ideal thing would be to load the user's notifications one time as soon as they login and go to their dashboard and then continue to show that number across all pages unless they check the notifications, then the number clears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an action and against that action create a partial view and in the **_Layout.cshtml** call it, this will save you from code duplication and `ViewData` :

You action code will look like:

```
public ActionResult Notifications()
{
   var model = Model.Notifications.Count();
   return View("_NotificationsPartial",model);
}
```

your partial view **_NotificationsPartial.cshtml** would be like:

```
@model System.Int32

<a href="#">Notifications 
<span class="badge">@Model</span>
```

Now you just need to call it in your **_Layout.csthml**:

```
@Html.Action("Notifications","SomeController")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thanks! The only thing I am still confused about is which controller I would put the ActionResult in that binds the model of the partial. I guess I would create a general controller. Also, @Html.Action is not available in ASP.NET Core for some reason any suggestions?

Comment: in core we have components now, you will need to make one, see : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/294/view-components-in-asp-net-core-mvc